# ¿Cómo optimizar este código?

Tags: python, random

Me gustaría optimizar el código porque creo que es demasiado largo para lo que hace. Soy nuevo y cualquier ayuda me viene bien.
Este programa me lo propuso mi profesor como tarea, pero yo he decidido llevarlo más allá. He querido ponerle varias dificultades y algún "easter egg". Ya lo he entregado, pero aun así me gustaría saber como mejorarlo.

> El programa es como un juego en el cual tienes que adivinar el número, además este posee varias dificultades.

https://github.com/GGD708/GGD708/blob/main/Programa_adivinar_numero_v2.py

Comment: Hola bienvenido a Stackoverflow, por favor has el [tour] para entender cómo funcionamos y de paso ganar tu primer medalla. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Debes colocar el código de lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento. Te sugiero que leas [example] para que sea más fácil entender lo que buscas. Este tipo de preguntas suelen cerrarse debido a que está basada en opiniones. Saludos

Comment: Dos cosas. Primero, no pases codigo por links, si por algun motivo el link se cae, la pregunta se volvera inutil para futuros lectores. Segundo, creo que una pagina mas adecuada para este tipo de dudas (esta en ingles) es code review.

Comment: Por cierto, me gusta esa pasion que te lleva a agrandar tu programa c:

Answer (score 3):

El concepto de optimización debe ser mejor definido, ya que puede entenderse de dos formas:

1. Hacer que el programa se ejecute lo más rápidamente posible, o utlizando el mínimo de recursoe (memoria o CPU)
2. Hacer que el programa sea más corto, más fácil de leer y comprender.

Supongo que te estás refiriendo al segundo caso, y en eso me centraré.

### Tu código

Para futura referencia y por si el link proporcionado en la pregunta desapareciera, este es tu código. Es muy largo, pero por suerte StackOverflow muestra solo una parte y proporciona una barra de scroll para ver el resto.

```py
import random

intentosRealizados=0

misNombres=["Guillermo","Guille","GGD","GGD708",]

dificultades=[1,2,3,4]

variable1=False

dificultad1=False

dificultad2=False

dificultad3=False

dificultad4=False

dificultad_in_dificultades=False

name=input("¡Bienvenido! Por favor introduzca su nombre: ") 

if name in misNombres:
    print("¿Creador eres tú?")
    variable1=True
else:
    print("""
Hola """+name+""", yo me llamo IANA y mi creador es Guillermo.
Soy una inteligencia artificial con la que puedes jugar,
específicamente a intentar adivinar el número que estoy pensando.""")

    dificultad=int(input("""
Este juego tiene 3 niveles de dificultad. En la dificultad 1
tendrás 8 intentos y 20 números a elegir. En la 2 solo tendrás
5 intentos, pero seguirá siendo entre los mismos números. En
la 3 tendrás 5 intentos, pero entre 40 números. Y como novedad
contamos con la dificultad 4, esta es personalizable. 

Escoge una dificultad: """))

    if dificultad in dificultades:
        
        dificultad_in_dificultades=True

    while dificultad_in_dificultades==False:
        dificultad=int(input("""
Esa dificultad no es válida.
Escoge una dificultad: """))
        if dificultad in dificultades:
        
            dificultad_in_dificultades=True
    
    if dificultad==1 and variable1==False and dificultad_in_dificultades==True:
            
            print("""
Has escogido la primera dificultad.""")
            
            numero=random.randint(1,20)
            
            dificultad1=True

            while intentosRealizados<8 and dificultad1==True:

                estimacion=int(input("""
Escribe un número: """))

                intentosRealizados=intentosRealizados+1

                if estimacion<1:
                    print("¡Ese número es muy pequeño! Recuerda que los limites son el 1 y el 20.")
                elif estimacion<numero-2:
                    print("Tu estimación es muy baja.")
                elif estimacion<numero:
                    print("Tu estimación es baja")
                elif estimacion>20:
                    print("!Te has pasado! Ese número es mayor de 20. Recuerda que es del 1 al 20.")
                elif estimacion>numero+2:
                    print("Tu estimación es muy alta")
                elif estimacion>numero:
                    print("Tu estimación es alta")
                elif estimacion==numero:
                    break
        
    elif dificultad==2 and variable1==False and dificultad_in_dificultades==True:

            print("""
Has escogido la segunda dificultad.""")
            
            numero=random.randint(1,20)
            
            dificultad2=True

            while intentosRealizados<5 and dificultad2==True:

                estimacion=int(input("""
Escribe un número: """))

                intentosRealizados=intentosRealizados+1

                if estimacion<1:
                    print("¡Ese número es muy pequeño! Recuerda que los limites son el 1 y el 20.")
                elif estimacion<numero-2:
                    print("Tu estimación es muy baja.")
                elif estimacion<numero:
                    print("Tu estimación es baja")
                elif estimacion>20:
                    print("!Te has pasado! Ese número es mayor de 20. Recuerda que es del 1 al 20.")
                elif estimacion>numero+2:
                    print("Tu estimación es muy alta")
                elif estimacion>numero:
                    print("Tu estimación es alta")
                elif estimacion==numero:
                    break

    elif dificultad==3 and variable1==False and dificultad_in_dificultades==True:
            print("""
Has escogido la tercera dificultad.""")
            
            numero=random.randint(1,40)
            
            dificultad3=True

            while intentosRealizados<5 and dificultad3==True:

                estimacion=int(input("""
Escribe un número: """))

                intentosRealizados=intentosRealizados+1

                if estimacion<1:
                    print("¡Ese número es muy pequeño! Recuerda que los limites son el 1 y el 20.")
                elif estimacion<numero-2:
                    print("Tu estimación es muy baja.")
                elif estimacion<numero:
                    print("Tu estimación es baja")
                elif estimacion>40:
                    print("!Te has pasado! Ese número es mayor de 20. Recuerda que es del 1 al 20.")
                elif estimacion>numero+2:
                    print("Tu estimación es muy alta")
                elif estimacion>numero:
                    print("Tu estimación es alta")
                elif estimacion==numero:
                    break

    elif dificultad==4 and variable1==False and dificultad_in_dificultades==True:
        print("""
Has escogido la cuarta dificultad.
""")
        numeros=int(input("""A continuación, pon la cantidad máxima de números entre los que quieres jugar: """))

        intentos=int(input("""
Ahora escoge la cantidad de intentos que quieras tener: """))

        numero=random.randint(1,numeros)
            
        dificultad4=True

        while intentosRealizados<intentos and dificultad4==True:

            estimacion=int(input("""
Escribe un número: """))

            intentosRealizados=intentosRealizados+1

            if estimacion<1:
                numeros=str(numeros)
                print("¡Ese número es muy pequeño! Recuerda que los limites son el 1 y el " + numeros + ".")
                numeros=int(numeros)
            elif estimacion<numero-2:
                print("Tu estimación es muy baja.")
            elif estimacion<numero:
                print("Tu estimación es baja")
            elif estimacion>numeros:
                numeros=str(numeros)
                print("!Te has pasado! Ese número es mayor de " + numeros +". Recuerda que es del 1 al " + numeros + ".")
                numeros=int(numeros)
            elif estimacion>numero+2:
                print("Tu estimación es muy alta")
            elif estimacion>numero:
                print("Tu estimación es alta")
            elif estimacion==numero:
                break


if variable1==False:
    if estimacion==numero:
        intentosRealizados=str(intentosRealizados)
        print("""
¡Genial, """ + name + "! Lo has logrado en " + intentosRealizados + """ intentos.

¡Adios!""")
    else:
        numero=str(numero)
        print("Es una pena, estaba pensando en el " + numero + ". ¡Más suerte la proxima vez!")
```

### Cuestiones de formato

- El código usa en algunas líneas espacios y en otras tabuladores. Mientras el uso de uno u otro sea consistente dentro del mismo bloque python lo admite, pero a la larga esta forma de trabajar acaba causando problemas al añadir por ejemplo una línea en un bloque que use espacios cuando la anterior estaba usando indentaciones. Es mejor usar siempre espacios para indentar.
- Hay muchas líneas en blanco en el código. Se recomienda usar líneas en blanco para separar la definición de una función de la siguiente, o en algunos casos para separar bloques de código, pero no son necesarias para separar cada una de las inicializaciones de variable, etc. Menos líneas en blanco significa más código visible a la vez en el editor, y por tanto más fácil de leer.
- El código usa en varios lugares cadenas delimitadas por triple comilla. Este tipo de cadena admite en su interior retornos de carro, y ésta es la razón por la que las usas, pero tiene el inconveniente de que "rompe" visualmente la indentación del programa. Aunque Python entiende que el contenido de esa cadena va aparte de la indentación del bloque y no da errores, lo cierto es que para los humanos resulta difícil leer un programa que rompa la indentación del código dentro de estas cadenas. Por otro lado si metes espacios por la izquierda para mejorar la indentación, esos espacios saldrán al hacer el `print()` de esa cadena cuando ejecutes el programa.

  Yo recomiendo usar las cadenas de triple comilla sólo para documentción del código (*docstrings*) y usar en los `print()` cadenas normales, que contengan en su interior `\n` donde quieras un salto de línea.

  Si la cadena es demasiado larga y quieres escribirla en varias líneas dentro del código, puedes convertirla en varias cadenas y unirlas con un `+`

  Por ejemplo:

  ```py
  print(
      f"Hola {name}, yo me llamo IANA y mi creador es Guillermo.\n" +
      "Soy una inteligencia artificial con la que puedes jugar,\n" +
      "específicamente a intentar adivinar el número que estoy pensando."
  )
  ```

### Cuestiones de lógica

- No necesitas muchas de las condiciones que habías puesto en el código. Por ejemplo, si verificas que el nombre es un de `misNombres`, el programa en realidad no hace nada más, tal como lo tienes, pues `variable1` se hace `True` y no entrará por ninguno de tus `if`. Así que puedes simplificar mucho el código si simplemente haces `quit()` cuando detectas que el nombre es uno de `misNombres`. Evitas así la `variable1` y todas las condiciones asociadas a ella, y también reduces un nivel de indentación todo el código al no ser necesario el primer `else:`
- No necesitas los booleanos `dificultad1`, `dificultad2`, etc... La comparación `if dificultad == 1` es igual de eficiente que `if dificultad1==True`. Es más, ni siquieras necesitas verificar en los bucles que `dificultad1` sea `True`. Siempre va a serlo porque ese bucle está dentro del `if dificultad == 1`. Así se simplifica más el código.
- Tampoco necesitas el booleano `dificultad_en_dificultades` que usas aqui:

```py
    dificultad = int(input(....))
    if dificultad in dificultades:
        dificultad_in_dificultades=True

    while dificultad_in_dificultades==False:
        dificultad=int(input("""
Esa dificultad no es válida.
Escoge una dificultad: """))
        if dificultad in dificultades:
            dificultad_in_dificultades=True
```

Todo eso se puede escribir de forma más sencilla así (aprovecho para cambiar  la cadena con triple comilla por una normal)

```py
dificultad = int(input(...))
while not dificultad in dificultades:
    dificultad = int(
        input("Esa dificultad no es válida.\nEscoge una dificultad: ")
    )
```

Fíjate como el primer `if` no es necesario, pues el `while` ya hace esa función. Si `dificultad` está en `dificultades` la condición del while será falsa y no se ejecutará su cuerpo. Si en cambio no lo está, se ejecutará el bucle hasta que esté.

**Otro detalle.** En python una variable booleana ya es en sí misma una condición, por lo que en vez de poner `if variable == True` puedes poner simplemente `if variable:` y en vez de `if variable == False:` puedes poner `if not variable`. Esto ayuda a que el programa sea más fácil de leer, especialmente si eliges un buen nombre para la variable. Por ejemplo, lo que tú habías llamado `variable1` (aunque ya la hemos eliminado pues no era necesaria como antes vimos), mejor se habría llamado `is_creator`. Así tus condiciones se leerían casi como frases en inglés: `if is_creator` o `if not is_creator`.

### Uso de f-strings

Me he fijado que cuando quieres mostrar por pantalla un mensaje que incluya el valor de una variable, conviertes la variable en cadena para concatenarla con otras, y luego la vuelves a convertir a entero. Por ejemplo aqui:

```
if estimacion<1:
    numeros=str(numeros)
    print("¡Ese número es muy pequeño! Recuerda que los limites son el 1 y el " + numeros + ".")
    numeros=int(numeros)
```

No es necesario complicarlo tanto. Python tiene (desde la versión 3.7) un tipo de cadena llamado f-strings que permite incrustar dentro valores de variables. Eso te permite escribir lo anterior así:

```
if estimacion<1:
    print(f"¡Ese número es muy pequeño! Recuerda que los limites son el 1 y el {numeros}.")
```

Fíjate que la cadena tiene una `f` delante de la comilla de apertura. En su interior pones entre llaves las variables o expresiones que quieras mostrar.

### Repetición de código

Pero el error más evidente (típico en alguien que está empezando, no te preocupes por ello) es que tu código es muy repetitivo. Lo que hay que hacer cuando la dificultad es 1, 2, 3 o 4 es **prácticamente lo mismo**. Sólo varía la elección del número a adivinar y la cantidad de intentos de que se dispone.

Esto está pidiendo a gritos una **función**, que es un trozo de código que recibe unos parámetros (valores de variables) y que hace siempre lo mismo, aunque dependiente de esos valores.

Imagina que tienes una función llamada `juego()` a la que le pasas como parámetros `numeros`, `intentos` y `name`. Esa función se ocupa de llevar a cabo todo el juego, es decir, básicamente consiste en extraer el código que ya tenías en el caso de dificultad 4, solo que las variables  `numeros` e `intentos` no se le piden al usuario, sino que se reciben como parámetros, y añadirle la parte final en que se muestra al usuario qué tal lo hizo.

Esa función sería por tanto así:

```
def juego(numeros, intentos, name):
    intentosRealizados = 0
    numero = random.randint(1, numeros)
    while intentosRealizados < intentos:
        estimacion = int(input("Escribe un número: "))
        intentosRealizados = intentosRealizados + 1
        if estimacion < 1:
            print(f"¡Ese número es muy pequeño! Recuerda que los limites son el 1 y el {numeros}.")
        elif estimacion < numero - 2:
            print("Tu estimación es muy baja.")
        elif estimacion < numero:
            print("Tu estimación es baja")
        elif estimacion > numeros:
            print(f"!Te has pasado! Ese número es mayor de {numeros}. Recuerda que es del 1 al {numeros}.")
        elif estimacion > numero + 2:
            print("Tu estimación es muy alta")
        elif estimacion > numero:
            print("Tu estimación es alta")
        elif estimacion == numero:
            break
    if estimacion == numero:
        print(f"¡Genial, {name}! Lo has logrado en {intentosRealizados} intentos.\n¡Adios!")
    else:
        print(f"Es una pena, estaba pensando en el {numero}. ¡Más suerte la proxima vez!")
```

Una vez tienes esta función, tu "programa principal" la llamará con unos parámetros u otros según la dificultad elegida. El programa principal queda entonces así de simple:

```py
if dificultad == 1:
    print("\nHas escogido la primera dificultad.")
    juego(numeros=20, intentos=8, name=name)
elif dificultad == 2:
    print("\nHas escogido la segunda dificultad.")
    juego(numeros=20, intentos=5, name=name)
elif dificultad == 3:
    print("\nHas escogido la tercera dificultad.")
    juego(numeros=40, intentos=5, name=name)
elif dificultad == 4:
    print("\nHas escogido la cuarta dificultad.")
    numeros = int(input("A continuación, pon la cantidad máxima de números entre los que quieres jugar: "))
    intentos = int(input("Ahora escoge la cantidad de intentos que quieras tener: "))
    juego(numeros=numeros, intentos=intentos)
```

Todo junto lo tienes [en este gist](https://gist.github.com/abul4fia/89d5343813ee841fdded51c6912c811a). No he querido incluirlo en la respuesta por no hacerla aún más larga. Aún así mi implementación tiene solo 74 líneas, frente a las 194 que tenía la tuya.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta c: Solo para agregar, Python también acepta una especie de sintaxis especial para concatenar cadenas literales sin usar +. Aquí un pequeño ejemplo: https://pastebin.com/8pigF8Nh Nota: solo sirve si todo lo que hay que concatenar son literales.

Comment: Sí, lo sé y suelo usarla. Funciona también para concatenar f-strings o un f-string con una cadena normal, etc. pero requiere que la secuencia de cadenas esté entre paréntesis (si quieres que se extienda en varias líneas, una cadena por línea). Pensé en meter eso pero me pareció una sintaxis un poco confusa para un principiante, que se puede confundir con que se están pasando varios parámetros al `print()`, como cuando se separan con comas. Así que preferí usar el `+` explícito. Esa concatenación de literales se hace en tiempo de "compilación" por lo que no penaliza en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: Demostración: https://pastebin.com/rhX8zkDa

Comment: Interesante! Tiene sentido que no lo agregases por evitar confusión.